# How to terminate application from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've tried varoius methods but none works. How to quit app from AlertDialog? I need it because I want to have function alertFatal() which quits application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quit an application then calling **finish** on the current running activity. For alert dialog this should work inside click handler of your dialog interface:

```
context.finish();//context can be this, or getActivity or just a valid context object.
```

Comment: This method doesn't work! The app doesn't finish! :(

Comment: there may be many reasons for this. You could provide more information like your activity code and test it in multiple devices. Without that all would be a random guess. U can under extreme scenarios use System.exit(0) but I suggest not to

Answer (score 0):

The finish() function should work. For example:

```
 AlertDialog exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Exit?")
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       MainActivity.this.finish(); //If you want to exit from the Main Acitvity
                   }
               })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)                           
        .create();
        exit.show();
```

Comment: It works fine for me. You mean that it doesn't quit?